# Why do you have to specify print in PyCharm to e.g. print(data.head)

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to import a CSV into pandas and view the data frame.  I'm following a tutorial that says I can e.g. retrieve the headers via `data.head()`.

This doesn't return anything when I run the program and I have to put `print` around everything to make it work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
path = "testdata"
os.chdir(path)
os.getcwd()

data = pd.read_csv("testdata.csv")

print(data.head())

list(data.columns.values)
```

Comment: obviously you have to `print` to see what `data.head()` returns that's why `print` is used

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. The tutorial perhaps talks about using the interactive python interpreter (running `python` from command line and then writing code) or about using Jupyter Notebook (this one has a built-in feature that automatically prints the last variable even without print). Using the `print()` function is very normal and it's very easy in python considering some other programming languages.

Comment: in normal script you have to use `print()` to display anything - and you can decide what you want to see. In Python Shell or in Jupyter it automatically displays every result to make life easier because in shell/jupyter most people want to see all results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output shown in Jupyter Notebook but not in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231992/output-shown-in-jupyter-notebook-but-not-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tutorial is expecting that you are typing your Python code at an interpreter's read-execute-display prompt (such as the command-line Python interpreter, or IDLE), normally indicated by `>>>`. But you are running your code in PyCharm as a program. If you want the behaviour you expect in PyCharm, ask it to open a Python console and type your code there.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, but you probably don't understand the meaning of return. `data.head()` returns the first five values of `data`. However, if you would use it like this:

```
data.head()
```

It will return into nothing, so whatever the function returns is discarded. You could either print the data that it returns in the console, like you did:

```
print(data.head())
```

Or you could save it in a variable and print that or do something else with it:

```
someVariable = data.head()
print(someVariable)
# Or do something with someVariable
```

---

If you are typing this code in the interpreter, the return value of `data.head()` would be written to the console automatically. Like this (from [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) example):

```
>>> df.head()
      animal
0  alligator
1        bee
2     falcon
3       lion
4     monkey
```